# Unable to map network drives or access AD DS tools - "The RPC Server is unavailable"

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, rpc

> This is a copy of a ticket I submitted with my own internal SysAdmin team.

I am unable to launch any Active Directory tools or map any shared drives (via batch file or manually). I have confirmed that the different file servers are pingable and there is no network communication issue.

Attached all relevant screenshots and debug logs.

Troubleshooting steps performed:

> Verified Corporate LAN connectivity
>   rebooted laptop
>   verified RPC Service was started
>   started RPC Locator service
>   performed ipconfig /flushdns and /registerdns to clear up potential name resolution issues

I also tested installing ADDS on another machine with my domain profile and was able to access without issue on that laptop.

The only major recent change I made to my current laptop was rebuilding it with a fresh company image early last week. I had no issues with shared drives or Active Directory until today.

Debug log .etl file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMugiNgJ2qtaUxpdjVPZmxKNzA/view?usp=sharing)

[image: ipconfig /all]

[image: Route print]

[image: RPC Server error]

Comment: It could be that the domain doesn't trust your computer. Have you tried removing the computer from the domain and then rejoining it?

Comment: I can access other intranet resources that require domain-level SSO authentication like our internal webapps accessible through the company sharepoint site.

Comment: If I were to resolve the trust relationship issue, is there a way of doing it without disjoining and rejoining the domain?

Comment: Is it problematic to remove it from the domain and rejoin?  As you said yourself, *"the only major recent change"* was completing reloading the operating system image.  That is a rather huge "only!"

Comment: The other SSO authentication happens on user level. There's no way I know that works and is easier than just disjoining and rejoining.

Comment: You can reset your computer from AD to re establish trust relations

Comment: So, I tried to disjoin and rejoin the domain on my laptop. This created a new problem where I couldn't rejoin the domain at all! just said that "the domain could not be reached"! 

I was able to confirm that I was on the Corporate LAN and intranet resources were pingable but it just did not want to rejoin the domain.

When I left the office on Monday I just set my laptop to reimage again, will see how it looks when I return tomorrow.